# Show that $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : |x|+|y|=2\} \subset \partial A$

Tags: real-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

> Let $A= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : |x|+|y|<2\}$. Show that $\{(x,y)
>  \in \mathbb{R}^2 : |x|+|y|=2\} \subset \partial A$.

As all norm are equivalents in $\mathbb{R}^2$, it is reasonable the use the norm $\| \cdot \|_1$ on our open balls, i.e. $(\mathbb{R}^2,\| \cdot \|_1)$.

So let $(x_0,y_0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $|x_0|+|y_0|=2.$

We want to show that for each $r>0$, $B((x_0,y_0),r) \cap A \not= \emptyset$ and $B((x_0,y_0),r) \cap \mathbb{R}^2-A \not= \emptyset.$

$r>\|(x,y)-(x_0, y_0)\| = \|(x-x_0, y-y_0)\| = |x-x_0|+ |y-y_0| \geq |x|-|x_0|+|y|-|y_0| = |x|+|y|-(|x_0|+|y_0|) = |x|+|y| - 2.$

I blocked on this problem for a while. Is anyone could help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $B=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:|x|+|y|=2\}$.  We want to show that for all $(x,y)\in B$ all open balls around $(x,y)$ intersect both $A$ and $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus A$.

Given $(x,y)$ with $|x|+|y|=2$, set $(x_n,y_n)=(1-1/n)(x,y)$ for natural numbers $n$.  It's pretty obvious that $(x_n,y_n)\to (x,y)$. We have $|x_n|=(1-1/n)|x|$ and $|y_n|=(1-1/n)|y|$ so that $|x_n|+|y_n|<|x|+|y|=2$ and so $(x_n,y_n)\in A$.  Every open ball around $(x,y)$ must contain some elements of $(x_n,y_n)$ since they converge to $(x,y)$, and so every such ball intersects $A$.

For $\mathbb{R}^2$, set $(x_n',y_n')=(1+1/n)(x,y)$. They lie in $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus A$ and also converge to $(x,y)$, so every open ball around $(x,y)\in B$ contains some $(x_n', y_n')$, and so intersects $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus A$.

Comment: I think your argument is clever. However, I don't see the link between sequences et open balls. What is the theorem allows you to use sequence instead of open ball?

Comment: @ForgotALot I think it should be usefull to explain why you can use sequence whereas this kind a proof has to use open balls.

Comment: The definition of convergent sequence $p_n$ in Baby Rudin 3.1 is that, for every $\epsilon>0$, we have $d(p_n,p)<\epsilon$ ($p$ being the limit) for all sufficiently large $n$.  In euclidean spaces like $\mathbb{R}^2$, sets $\{x:d(x,p)<\epsilon\}$ are the open balls around $p$.  Thus, convergence of a sequence to $p$ means that every open ball around $p$ contains points in the sequence.  Because the OP's definition of $\partial A$ was based on every open ball containing a point in $A$ and a point not in $A$, that was what I tried to show (using sequences), and is what I believe I have shown.